# Terminal 'ionic start' gives npm ERR

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to start my first ionic project based on VUE, following the steps on https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/cli

I reinstalling nodejs, tried uninstalling ionic > npm cache clear --force > reinstall, as well as launching Visual Studio Code in admin mode. Keep getting same error below. I am out of options, any advice?

```html
? Starter template: blank
√ Preparing directory .\myapp in 1.41ms
√ Downloading and extracting blank starter in 320.71ms
> ionic integrations enable capacitor --quiet -- myapp io.ionic.starter
> npm.cmd i --save -E @capacitor/core@latest
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network aborted
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-18T02_58_39_592Z-debug-0.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm.cmd i --save -E @capacitor/core@latest exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.

Installing dependencies may take several minutes.

  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

         Ionic Advisory, tailored solutions and expert services by Ionic

                             Go to market faster
                    Real-time troubleshooting and guidance
        Custom training, best practices, code and architecture reviews
      Customized strategies for every phase of the development lifecycle

               Learn more: https://ion.link/advisory

  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────


> npm.cmd i
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
npm ERR! 13168:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:677:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-18T02_59_54_033Z-debug-0.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm.cmd i exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue myself but not had much chance to do any digging in to why it's doing it yet but could be a breaking change in a newer version of Angular which the Ionic team haven't picked up on.

In the meantime (assuming you're using Angular), use:

`ng serve` and access it at `http://localhost:4200`.

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for reply, I am actually using Vue. I think I should add that in original question.